# Return a value from Future in dart

Tags: dart, flutter

Can we return or get the value from a Future object in dart. By reading the docs i could understand that we can pass a function in then method of Future class, but still i am clueless how can we return the value.

Consider following as pseudo code

```
Int getTotalPay(){
Future<int> pension = getPensionFundAPI(); // a long running api call. don't wait here and call to next api
int salary = getTotalSalary();
//wait here till we get the int value received in Future when the above api call completes.
int result = salary + pension;
print(result);
```

return result;
    }

i know i can make call to Future.then and pass a callback method in there. but my purpose is to return the result outside of then. same as we do in java and other oops language.

is it possible in dart?

Comment: use `Future#then` method, like: `pension.then((p) => print('result: ${salary + p}'));`

Comment: Basically I want to return the value back to the calling function. For clearity I have edited and renamed the main method.

Comment: so you have to return a `Future` and the calling function have to use `then()` method

Comment: Then future has to go along all the way. Strange. Might be true

Comment: why strange? if something can be completed in the future you cannot get it "now" - you have to pass that `Future` to the caller

Comment: This might be the way how dart works. But consider a similar Java example.   Future<Integer> result = getPensionFunds(); // this will execute in asyc manaer and will not block the execution of next statements untill we call result.get() to get the integer value. But here in dart we have to pass a callback even if I just want the result value. And a future row will start ..

Comment: you dont have to pass a callback - you have to pass a `Future`

Comment: Java's `Future.get()` "Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result": https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/Future.html You said you don't want to "block the execution". The quest for the impossible indeed.

Comment: @gazihan may be I made the things complex here. Can we do the same in flutter as Future.get do in the java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. Just like bringing your 80 year old self to here and now is not possible :)

However, you can write code that looks like it's possible, but actually is running different parts of a single function in different times. For that, you need to learn about the [`async` and `await` keywords](https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/futures#async-await).

Comment: I have been using await async since it's intro. But thing is I have ended up in a scenario where I need to get the value of future. It does possible in other languages. Plus above can also be achieved using this. But not exactly

Comment: Which language lets you get the value of a future right now?

Comment: As you have commented. In Java We can call to a method at say line number 1 get the future. Then perform other work in next 10 lines. And then when required make a call to Future.get. it will wait till we get the result. But we will have the value. Is similar behavior possible in Dart

Comment: `await` is exactly like Java's `.get()`, but you have to be in an `async` function. You can get the future, do other stuff and when you want the value you can do `await`. `.get()` actually blocks the thread and it is intentionally not there in Dart because blocking the UI thread hangs the app.

Comment: This make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I understand your question is: you don't want your code to stop and wait for the future to complete, instead in the meantime, while it completes, the code should continue excecuting/calculating other stuff. And if this other stuff is done before your future is, only then do you want it to wait.
This may be usefull when the code inside the future will have to wait itself (examples include a Network call or reading from disc) and you want to use that waiting time to calculate the rest.

For that I would recommend `Future.wait()`.
Simply wrap the 'other code' inside a method returning a future itself and pass them both to `Future.wait()`. This takes a list of futures, excecute all simultaneously and return all of their results once all are complete. For more information see: [Dart Docs: Future class - wait method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-async/Future/wait.html).
Example code, inspired by the example on the documentation:

```
int getTotalPay() async {
  List<int> values = await Future.wait([getPensionFundAPI(), getTotalSalary()]);
  int totalPay = values[0] + values[1];
  print(totalPay );
  return totalPay;
}

Future<int> getPensionFundAPI() async {
  // TODO: implement proper pension api
  int pension = 2;
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
  return pension;
}

Future<String> getTotalSalary() async {
  // TODO: implement proper salary calculating
  int salary = 3;
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  return salary;
}
```

Comment: Interesting function, which I was unaware of until I read your answer.

Comment: I'm glad you found my answer usefull, it took me quite a bit of research to find that function when I had OPs question myself. Please consider upvoting helpful answers to show future solution seekers to find the right answers more easily.

Comment: Sorry; I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `await`, but you method needs `async`.
I think that your method will be like this:

```
void main() async {
  int pension = await getPensionFundAPI(); // a long running api call. don't wait here and call to next api
  int salary = getTotalSalary();
  //wait here till we get the int value received in Future when the above api call completes.
  int result = salary + pension;
  print(result);
}
```

so await will block the method until the value is returned.

Comment: But I don't want to block the execution. That's why I think I should use future API here instead of await

Comment: you can call in another method, the async methods don't block the main thread if are in another thread.